# How can I dynamically append the ALT or TITLE tag an image?

Tags: jquery, html, css

**Question**: How can I dynamically append the ALT or TITLE tag an image?

```
Code:
<div class="country">
<img src="Flag.png" title="" alt="">
<img src="World.png" title="" alt="">
<img src="Man.png" title="" alt="">
<img src="Woman.png" title="" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: `$("img).attr("title", "text"), $("img).attr("alt", "text")`

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('img').eq(0).attr('alt','Flag').attr('title','Flag')
console.log("alt "+$('img').eq(0).attr('alt'))//setter
console.log("title "+$('img').eq(0).attr('title'))//getter
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="country">
<img src="Flag.png" title="" alt="">
<img src="World.png" title="" alt="">
<img src="Man.png" title="" alt="">
<img src="Woman.png" title="" alt="">
</div>
```

Use `.attr()`